# Where can I download old 32 bit Ver of WMWare Player for Linux Host

Tags: linux, vmware, download, 32-bit

**The Problem:**

1. I have an older 32 bit machine that was running a Windows 2000 guest on a Linux host using VMware Player.
2. The Windows 2000 guest was suspended (ie "not" powered down) before it was backed up.
3. The Linux host lost power during upgrade and all a data was lost.
4. I'm trying to restore the Windows 2000 guest on a 64 bit machine running VMware Workstation 15.x but it can't open the file because Windows 2000 was suspended "not" powered down before it was backed up.

**Solution:** Install a 32 bit version of VMware on the old computer, load the backed up copy of the Windows 2000 guest, then properly power it down and save a copy.

**Requirement:** Where can I download a 32 bit version of VMware Player or VMware Workstation for Linux.

**Note:** VMware no longer supports 32 bit versions and has removed all downloads from its site. All searches either link to a blank page on the VMware site or only refer to versions for Windows hosts.

Comment: What versions of Workstation is the VM configured to work with?  If you "upgrade" the VM to a new versions then you won't be able to start the VM in older versions 32-bit versions of VMWare Player.  You can edit your question to include the necessary information to answer your question.

Comment: Given that I went as far back as [VMWare Workstation 12 Pro](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/downloads/details?downloadGroup=WKST-1200-LX&productId=524) and it was still 64-bit.  This tells me that a 32-bit version of VMWare Player or VMWare Workstation is no longer available. [7.0 is also 64-bit only](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/downloads/details?downloadGroup=PLAYER-700&productId=466)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/400818/how-to-install-vmware-player-on-32-bit-13-10-without-64-bit-virtualisation

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading old versions of VMware Player here:

http://www.oldversion.com/windows/vmware-player/

This is not a VMware site so I do not vouch for it.

VMware Player 5 is there - a number of old versions are there as well.

Old versions are not available from VMware.com. My own store of versions only goes back as far as version 14.

Also, to go back that far you may need to use VMware Workstation.

https://qabay.co/?utm_term=Vmware+workstation+32+bit+linux&lang=EN

Again, I do not vouch for old software. I am just trying to help you.

There are also old versions here:

https://www.ecityworks.com/vmware-workstation-old-version-download

Finally anything you wish to try with old versions of VMware can be done on a Windows host, so there is something here for you.

Comment: oldversion is a good site, use it all the time

Comment: “My own store of versions only goes back as far as version 14.” - I had no problem finding older versions, but they were all 64-but, which the author didn’t want

Comment: There were 32-bit versions on “old versions “ as far as I could see. I hope this is helping the OP

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did check out the old versions web site. The only VMware Players or Workstations were for Windows hosts and not the ones needed for a Linux host.

Comment: I cannot find really old Linux versions but you can install the older Windows versions on older machines and try restoring the Windows 2000 machine that way.

Comment: I added another site to my answer where old versions are available. Try that as well.